# Group list of dict results using python based on first key from each item

Tags: python

I am trying to find the output of this `list` of `dict` using Python. Because `foo` and `data` are unique keys, the output should merge them.

```py
input = [{'foo': 'foo-main-123'}, {'foo': 'foo-main-345'}, {'data': 'data-main-111'}]
output = {'foo', ['foo-main-123', 'foo-main-345'], 'data': ['data-main-111']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then iterate each k,v pair in each dict in input.

try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

input = [{'foo': 'foo-main-123'}, {'foo': 'foo-main-345'}, {'data': 'data-main-111'}]
output = defaultdict(list)
for d in input:
    for k,v in d.items():
        output[k].append(v)
output=dict(output)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': ['foo-main-123', 'foo-main-345'], 'data': ['data-main-111']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I learned about  defaultdict(list), very powerful